# The localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ at every prime ideal is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, localization, integral-domain

> I want to show that the localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ at every prime ideal is an integral domain.

$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is not an integral domain since $(0,1)\cdot(1,0)=(0,0)$. I think $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})_P$ wouldn't be an integral domain for similar reason. Can anyone explain what difference the localization can make here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You say “at its prime ideal”. Are you saying there is only one prime idea? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin sorry I meant every prime ideal

Comment: Then edit the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every localization of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain because every localization of $\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, because $\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain. This follows immediately from the following simple fact:

> If $R$ and $S$ are commutative unital rings and $P\subset R\times S$ is a prime ideal, then, after switching $R$ and $S$ if necessary, we have $P=Q\times S$, where $Q\subset R$ is a prime ideal, from which it follows that
>   $$(R\times S)_P\cong R_Q.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might be helpful if anyone is wondering why $P=Q\times S$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2235763/if-a-is-a-prime-ideal-on-r-times-s-then-a-p-times-s-where-p-is-a-prim/2235808#2235808